# Raspberry Pi 2 and SH1106 OLED

Tags: raspbian, i2c, wiring, spi

> Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

I am trying to get a cheap SH1106 1.3" OLED from eBay working with my Raspberry Pi 2. Frm the eBay description, it says that it supports "I2C/IIC Interface, need only 2 IO". I am however not able to have it detected by i2cdetect (only gives me --).

The module has 7 pins: GND, VCC, CLK, MOSI, RES, DC, CS. I have tried different wirings. Is this module SPI only? (wrong description).

Which pin is supposed to be connected as SDA/Data if using I2C?

EDIT: http://www.ebay.com/itm/221517696686

Comment: Please edit your question and add a link to the specific ebay part you bought, there are several varieties of this part. I would try mosi and clk.

Comment: The title only mentions SPI, you may be out of luck with regards to I2C. But you may want to check this first it mentions that I2C also needs the RST pin https://learn.adafruit.com/monochrome-oled-breakouts/wiring-1-dot-3-128x64 This may help as well https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-oled-displays-for-raspberry-pi

Comment: I am trying to get this going: https://github.com/rm-hull/ssd1306 (I have a RPi 2 B)

Comment: On the back of the display: 2 pads for SPI (connected), 2 pads for ICC (not connected).. Is ICC related to I2C somehow?

Comment: This is only my assumption based off of the pics on the eBay listing and the adafruit site. But it would appear that to get I2c to work would require modifying the jumpers on the back of the board. I suggest you follow the instructions from the adafruit links to get it working via SPI

Answer (score 0):

Desolder the resistor R3, solder it on the vacant R1 slot and add up a 4.7k at the vacant R8 slot. [image]For the IIC communication 4pins should connected between the module and the arduino; SCK, SCL, RES and DC.

More info is here:
[1.3" Serial OLED Display Module](https://www.rhydolabz.com/wiki/?p=12752)